# what am i doing wrong with tkinter application for email slicer?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

making an email slicer,
some errors I'm getting are:
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'index'
ValueError: substring not found
now, with this specific code, I'm getting no result at all, it just doesn't do anything when I click the button

> ```
> root = Tk()
> e = Entry(root)
> e.grid(row = 6, column = 6)
> s = Label(root)
> s.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
> wel = Label(root, text = "whats your email")
> wel.grid(row = 1, column = 5)
> inp = Entry(root)
> inp.grid(row = 3, column = 5)
> def callback(re = inp.get()):
>         us = re[:re.startswith("@")]
>         uss = re[re.startswith("@")+1:]
> var = StringVar()
> var.set(us + uss)
> sub = Button(root, text = "submit", command = lambda:callback())
> sub.grid(row = 5, column = 5)
> final = Label(root, textvariable = var)
> final.grid(row = 5, column = 6)
>
> root.mainloop()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- call `inp.get()` inside `callback()`, not as default value of argument
- use `find()` instead of `startswith()`
- call `var.set(...)` inside the function as well

```
def callback():
    re = inp.get()
    pos = re.find("@")
    if pos >= 0:
        user = re[:pos]
        domain = re[pos+1:]
        var.set(user+","+domain)
    else:
        var.set("Invalid email")
```

Note that above is not enough to check whether the input email is valid or not, for example two "@" in the input.